# What are the benefits of running Apache Spark on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, spark

When running Apache Spark one submits jobs to a Cluster Manager. The cluster manager is delegated with the task of accepting / declining requests for resources. The cluster manager could either be YARN, Mesos, Spark Standalone or Kubernetes.

What are the benefits of using Kubernetes as the cluster manager?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one good reason is you can have multiple applications running different versions of spark. Say you have a very stable complicated application running on spark 2.1, and tomorrow you are required to build a new spark application. If you run Spark on Kubernetes your new app can run in the same Kubernetes cluster but using a newer version of Spark which might allow you to take advantage of some new features that pain you in the older stable application.